# What is the correct way to yield from a stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-asyncio, yield-from

I have a `Connection` type that I’m using to wrap read/write stream pairs from `asyncio`.

```
class Connection(object):

    def __init__(self, stream_in, stream_out):
        self._streams_ = (stream_in, stream_out)

    def read(self, n_bytes: int = -1):
        stream = self._streams_[0]
        return stream.read(n_bytes)

    def write(self, bytes_: bytes):
        stream = self._streams_[1]
        stream.write(bytes_)
        yield from stream.drain()
```

When a new client connects to the server, `new_connection` will create a new `Connection` object, and expect to receive 4 bytes.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def new_connection(stream_in, stream_out):
    conn = Connection(stream_in, stream_out)
    data = yield from conn.read(4)
    print(data)
```

The client sends 4 bytes.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def client(loop):
    ...
    conn = Connection(stream_in, stream_out)
    yield from conn.write(b'test')
```

This works about as I expect, but I do have to write `yield from` for every call to `read` and `write`. I've tried moving the `yield from` into `Connection` for this reason.

```
def read(self, n_bytes: int = -1):
    stream = self._streams_[0]
    data = yield from stream.read(n_bytes)
    return data
```

But, instead of the expected data bytes, I get a generator object.

```
<generator object StreamReader.read at 0x1109983b8>
```

So, for every call to `read` and `write`, I must be careful to have the `yield from`. My goal is to reduce `new_connection` to the following.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def new_connection(stream_in, stream_out):
    conn = Connection(stream_in, stream_out)
    print(conn.read(4))
```

Comment: Why do you have to yield from? If you don't yield from conn.read(4), it looks to me like it simply returns a bytes object. Is that what you are looking for here?

Comment: @RageCage: Without `yield from`ing, `conn.read(4)` still returns a generator: `<generator object Connection.read at 0x1019262b0>`

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified; if you don't yield from the first iteration of conn.read() (the single line version) what is the result?

Comment: @RageCage: If you mean `def read(self, n_bytes): return self.__in.read(n_bytes)` in conjunction with `data = conn.read(4)`, I'm still getting a generator (`Connection.read`).

Comment: Sounds like there is some context I'm missing. The StreamReader.read function should return a regular byte array, so if you never use the yield keyword anywhere in the reading workflow a generator should never be made.

Comment: @RageCage: This is in the context of asynchronous I/O and coroutines with the `asyncio` module.

Comment: I have posted a possible answer that explains some concepts and attaches some resources. Hopefully we can work off it to get your code working as you need it to. Your particular problem is very difficult to reproduce in exactly this context, so if missing information can fill in the gaps then that would be very helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153290/discussion-between-ragecage-and-zach-gates).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`StreamReader.read` is a coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.read), your only options for calling it are a) wrapping it in a [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task) or [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#future) and running that via an event loop, b) `await`ing it from coroutine defined with `async def`, or c) using `yield from` with it from a coroutine defined as a function decorated with `@asyncio.coroutine`.

Since `Connection.read` is called from an event loop (via the coroutine `new_connection`), you can't reuse that event loop to run a `Task` or `Future` for `StreamReader.read`: [event loops can't be started while they're already running](https://tio.run/##hY6xCsMwDER3fYVGa8nSrdBvMW6qtAZHErZSyNe7xLTQpXQ77h6Ps90fKqfe82paHVPbZc4KMALeeMFFNdAZEIuq4eWDTHf2yE8Wj8cQ6E1MdZO4iecSZ12tsHO4phqIvqWjOaSWWgP4p/4lHt@o9xc). You'd either have to [stop the event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.stop) (disastrous and probably not possible to do correctly) or [create a new event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.new_event_loop) (messy and defeating the purpose of using coroutines). Neither of those are desirable, so `Connection.read` needs to be a coroutine or an `async` function.

The other two options (`await` in an `async def` coroutine or `yield from` in a `@asyncio.coroutine`-decorated function) are mostly equivalent. The only difference is that [`async def` and `await` were added in Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/), so for 3.4, using `yield from` and `@asyncio.coroutine` is the only option (coroutines and `asyncio` didn't exist prior to 3.4, so other versions are irrelevant). Personally, I prefer using `async def` and `await`, because defining coroutines with `async def` is cleaner and clearer than with the decorator.

In brief: have `Connection.read` and `new_connection` be coroutines (using either the decorator or the `async` keyword), and use `await` (or `yield from`) when calling other coroutines (`await conn.read(4)` in `new_connection`, and `await self.__in.read(n_bytes)` in `Connection.read`).

Comment: Ah, very nice answer Mego! This is clearly written by someone who knows what their talking about. I learned much from reading it. +1

Answer (score 2):

I found a chunk of the [StreamReader source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/streams.py) on line 620 is actually a perfect example of the function's usage.

In my previous answer, I overlooked the fact that `self.__in.read(n_bytes)` is not only a coroutine (which I should've known considering it was from the `asyncio` module XD) but it yields a result on line . So it is in fact a generator, and you will need to yield from it.

Borrowing this loop from the source code, your read function should look something like this:

```
def read(self, n_bytes : int = -1):
    data = bytearray() #or whatever object you are looking for
    while 1:
        block = yield from self.__in.read(n_bytes)
        if not block:
            break
        data += block
    return data
```

Because `self.__in.read(n_bytes)` is a generator, you have to continue to yield from it until it yields an empty result to signal the end of the read. Now your read function should return data rather than a generator. You won't have to yield from this version of `conn.read()`.

Comment: Using the function exactly as you've provided it, I'm still receiving a generator object (`Connection.read`).

Comment: Are you still yielding from the conn.read call? Try printing data and type(data) in the read function to see what it is before returning.

Comment: No, I removed that and tried `data = conn.read(4)` instead. It is a generator.

Comment: Using `yield from` like this won't work, because `StreamReader.read` isn't a generator - it's a coroutine. The two different uses of `yield from` (delegating with generators and handing off control between coroutines) is exactly why the `await` keyword was introduced in 3.5.